# Entries going to 404 pages

Tags: entries

I have a site setup which works, I have basically copied it across because I need to duplicate it and change content.

I am using Structure module, but any content I add it goes to a 404 page.

Is there anything I can show to help find out the problem to this.  Driving me mad because I can't think what I've missed.

Comment: Is it a root Structure page, or deeper (parent)?  What is the template that is being used - look in the Structure tab in the Publish/Edit screen. Can you access template-group/template in your URLs? As in could it be a htaccess rewrite issue - does it work with index.php in the path?

Comment: Yeah I'd check that all the entries are linked to a template that actually works. I've had similar before where everything seems to be in order but the template is one that won't ever show the entries you're trying to display (i.e. was changed mysteriously from what it should've been).